# Fujitsu Esprimo E920 fan control

Tags: fancontrol, sensors

I am using a Fujitsu Esprimo E920 as a server. It is nice and quiet but controlling the fans seems tricky. There are two 4-pin fan headers (and a third not populated) that have the CPU fan and a case fan connected. There is a setting in the BIOS for normal or performance mode, in normal mode the fans don't run and the CPU temps read about 45C. The fans start to run when the CPU temperature hits 70C. In performance mode they spin at 1800 and 1200 rpm when the system is idle and don't spin any faster under full load. The CPU temps are about 25C idle to 66C under load.

Some testing with a fan placed externally where the case fan is running at 5V made the CPU temp drop to about 36C, so having just one fan run will be enough most of the times.
lm-sensors detects the fans so I can read the rpm. But pwmconfig tells me there are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed.

sensors tells me the fans are on the ISA adapter theseus-isa-0000

Are there no sensor modules available or is there a way to control the fans on this system?

Comment: Can you add the output of `sensors-detect`?

Comment: I'll just post the summary:
```
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: FUJITSU ESPRIMO E920
# Board: FUJITSU D3222-A1
# Kernel: 6.2.0-35-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz (6/60/3)



Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue:

Driver 'sch5636':
  * ISA bus, address 0x640
    Chip 'SMSC SCH5636 Super IO' (confidence: 9)

Driver 'coretemp':
  * Chip 'Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, no idea why the formatting does not work.

Comment: That's ok, there is enough info there, was looking for this part Driver 'sch5636': * ISA bus, address 0x640 Chip 'SMSC SCH5636 Super IO'

Comment: Edit the question and add the output of `sensors` for the theseus.

Comment: The sensor that does fan RPM:

$ sensors
theseus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
3.3V:          3.38 V
VREF:          1.06 V
VBAT:          2.76 V
3.3AUX:        3.38 V
12V:          12.17 V
fan1:        1825 RPM
fan2:        1199 RPM
fan4:           0 RPM
temp1:        +25.0°C
temp2:        +24.0°C
temp3:        +23.0°C
temp4:        +45.0°C
temp5:        +21.0°C
temp6:        +29.0°C
temp8:        +25.0°C